# Adding DELETE operation causes TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, http-delete, reserved-words

I created a Node.js rest api. It follows the general controller, model, schema structure and uses a restify server which I start by running `node index.js`.

The controller consists of a `controllers/baseController.js` which contains some operations relevant to all of my controller classes. My `controllers/issues.js` which extends `controllers/baseController.js` initially only had a GET, POST and PUT operations. Whilst not complete, these worked fine. They certainly didnt prevent the server fron starting.

I then added the following delete action to my controller:

```
controller.addAction({
  'path': '/issues',
  'method': 'DELETE',
  'summary': 'Delete all issues from the list',
  'responseClass': 'Issues',
  'nickname': 'deleteIssues'
}, controller.delete);
```

It routes to:

```
delete(req, res, next) {
  let collectionContents = this.lib.db.model('Issues');
  collectionContents.remove({}, (err, result) => {
    if(err) return next(this.RESTError('InternalServerError', err));
    this.writeHAL(res, result);
  });
}
```

However, when I try to start my server I get this error:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:30333/71b18332-4ac6-49b8-b0ac-86517e9a2190
Debugger attached.
/Users/paulcarron/git/issue-tracker/controllers/baseController.js:19
      app[method.toLowerCase()](act['spec']['path'], act['action']);
                               ^

    at Issues.setUpActions (/Users/paulcarron/git/issue-tracker/controllers/baseController.js:15:18)
    at Object.setupRoutes (/Users/paulcarron/git/issue-tracker/lib/helpers.js:13:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/paulcarron/git/issue-tracker/index.js:35:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:632:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
TypeError: app[method.toLowerCase(...)] is not a function
baseController.js:19
    at actions.forEach.act (/Users/paulcarron/git/issue-tracker/controllers/baseController.js:19:32)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Issues.setUpActions (/Users/paulcarron/git/issue-tracker/controllers/baseController.js:15:18)
    at Object.setupRoutes (/Users/paulcarron/git/issue-tracker/lib/helpers.js:13:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/paulcarron/git/issue-tracker/index.js:35:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:632:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

`baseController.js` is [here](https://github.com/runnerpaul/issue-tracker/blob/master/controllers/baseController.js).

It seems to have an issue with `'method': 'DELETE'`. However, I can't figure out why. I thought it may be Swagger related as I believe the functions such as `addGET`, `addPOST` etc are there and that maybe `addDELETE` doesn't exist but I checked and it's there. Can anybody explain what might be wrong here?

**Additional info.**
I think I'm making some progress. The specific point where I'm getting my issue is with `method.toLowerCase()`. When setting up `DELETE`, this is essentially `DELETE.toLowerCase()` but this isn't allowed because delete is a reserved word(I think). Does that seem correct and if so how wo I resolve it?

Comment: What is `app` in baseController?

Comment: App is the server.

Comment: 'server' can mean a lot of different things, but does your 'server' have a 'delete' method?

Comment: Apologies. That's true. It's a Restify server. Now that I think about it, I may have read something about deleting with Restify. I'll try to find it.

Comment: Could this actually be related to Swagger?

Comment: If your swagger specification can trigger calling a method on the wrong object, something is really wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Try to rephrase your own question so I can help you figure out the answer.